# Изменения при скроллинге

Tags: android

Например в WhatsAppе есть такая штучка, при скроллинге картинка(фотография) медленно затемняется и остается только заголовок а сама картинка исчезает и если скроллить вверх то обратно появляется.
**Вопрос:** Даже не знаю название этой штуки. Как это реализовать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Судя по всему вам нужен `CollapsingToolbarLayout` из `android.support.design` библиотеки от гугла.

Вот пример на англо-саксонсом: [Design Support Library (IV): Collapsing Toolbar Layout](http://antonioleiva.com/collapsing-toolbar-layout/)